# LaTeX distributor and editor downloaded, not showing there is a LaTeX distributor on my system

Tags: miktex, texstudio, installing

I am new to LaTeX and am trying to use it to create lecture notes in my mathematics lectures. Specifically, my problem has become that TeXStudio is showing that there are no LaTeX distributions on my system. From that, I downloaded MiKTeX Console, still showing that there are no distributors of LaTeX on my system.

Any help will be much appreciated, I am sure the answer will be obvious, but it appears that it is not so obvious to myself

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Which distribution did you install? And did you install it before the editor?

Comment: You need first to install MiKTeX. Available is on https://miktex.org/download. Its bundle contain beside MiKTeX also MiKTeX Console as well TeXWorks editor. If you more prefer TeXStudio, after installed MiKTeX install alo it.

Comment: MiKTeX I believe (if it is a distribution), and I installed it after the editor.

Comment: Thanks Zarko, I downloaded the package and only got MiKTeX Console. I will try again.

Comment: Zarko, do I need to install MiKTeX before TeXStudio?

Comment: Yes, you have to install the distribution first, and the editor next.

Comment: Using a Mac (apologies for not providing that information), the download is only showing to install MiKTeX Console. Any suggestions?

Comment: I have just realised that you proceed to the MiKTeX Console, and thereafter install the packages